# arrayformula sum in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

How do you `arrayformula()` a `sum()` such as:

`=sum(A1:H1)`

I need to go down 1000 rows.

Comment: This is a very simple question that does not need complication.
Let us not complicate this.
Simply put parenthesis in each of the array in the range.

=arrayformula( Sum( (A1:A1000):(H1:H1000) )

Comment: =arrayformula( Sum( (A1:A1000):(H1:H1000) ), while simple, does not work in sheets as of today.  It seems to sum the entire range A1:H1000.

Comment: as a general matter, ArrayFormula will not compute correct results when composed around functions which themselves accept Range arguments.  The range argument is "grabbed" by the function with with ArrayFormula is being composed (the function used as an argument to ArrayFormula), and used it its computation, returning its result (often a scalar).  ArrayFormula will never see the input range, and have no capability to substitute for it as desired.
This is why it fails to work with Or(), And(), etc.

Comment: Created sample Google Sheet for experiments https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SfZwhA70jfXqMhb1cBZVvrioGuqYRD_DP4qJm_FvSvc

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Another option:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(A1:H1),ROW(A1:A1000)),ROW(A1:A1000),A1:H1000))
```

Comment: You're amazing. Worked. I'm using the new Google Spreadsheets now. If I change the formula to a more generic `=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(A1:H),ROW(A1:A)),ROW(A1:A),A1:H))` the top right loading bar just keeps going and never loads. Why is that? Too many calculations for even the new Google spreadsheet?

Comment: This is an issue I have previously escalated. IMO, array formulae referencing large arrays seem to have noticeably poorer performance in new Sheets compared with old. When referencing whole columns like this, try to ensure you have as few empty rows as possible.

Comment: Any idea on when they will get `importrange()` working on the new Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using a range for `column()`. Won't it always be 1?

Comment: Can you please explain why this works? Why can't you just do `=ArrayFormula(Sum(A1:H1))`?

Comment: Because `=ArrayFormula(...)` has no idea weather to output a row, or column vector. For example; `=Sum(A1:A5)` totals a row, `=Sum(A1:E1)` totals a column, `=Sum(A1:E5)` totals a field outputting 1 result. Putting `ArrayFormula` around it can do nothing to a single number.

Answer (score 25):

with new functions in google sheets (since 20 Sep, 2022) all you need is:

```
=BYROW(A:H; LAMBDA(x; SUM(x)))
```

[image]

Comment: wow. `LAMBDA`? looks like they also added `MAP` that's sick.

Comment: @jason Yes, no more guessing about whether ArrayFormula is going to work as you expect! It should also be noted that `MAP` applies to the entire 2d range, so that's handy if you want to transform every individual value.

Comment: ARRAYFORMULA is great. LAMBDA is superb.

Comment: I've just learned a whole level of behaviour in Google Sheets from this answer. I had no idea Sheets could be so functional.

Answer (score 15):

Of the two answers that work, Jacob Jan Tuinstra and AdamL, Jacob gives a better answer. Jacob's runs faster and is easier to remember.

However, why use crazy formulas when it is much easier to use Google Sheets to the fullest?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A+B2:B+C2:C+D2:D+E2:E+F2:F+G2:G+H2:H)
```

In the foregoing formula, you can use named ranges instead of the ranges by reference.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(range1+range2+range3+range4+range5+range6+range7+range8)
```

As well, you can sum across rows that span sheets rather than being stuck working with columns within the same sheet.

To fix the formula to block returning zeros for blank rows, use this:

```
=arrayFormula(if(isNumber(A2:A),A2:A+B2:B+C2:C+D2:D+E2:E+F2:F,G2:G,H2:H))
```

See: [See Ahab's answer on Google Forums](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/Q9x44sclzfY/olchGmcsQ_4J)

For a cool sum accumulation formula, see [Otávio Alves Ribeiro's answer on Google Forums](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/bkqdzpntYGQ/oDs1ypKCsDkJ)

Comment: Meanwhile, the answer is totally useful, more so, than the other answers.

Why bother trying to memorize or look up a convoluted formula pattern when all one need do is this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(test for data in rows, A2:A+B2:B))`

Comment: Oh well. It works for anyone who lives by the motto "time is money."

Comment: yeah but technical debt is also (negative) money.

Comment: As your solution works good for 8 columns, it's not that useful while there are 100 columns.

Answer (score 9):

This is what you are looking for:

```
=MMULT(A1:H1000,TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(A1:H1000)^0)))
```

See this answer on Web Application I gave: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/53419/29140

Note: tried it on the new Google Spreadsheet, without succes.

Comment: In new Sheets, MMULT will fail if blank cells are in the array. The workaround is to wrap the first argument in `VALUE()`.

Comment: for general propose maybe it easer to not repeat the range and  just write `MMULT(A1:H,{1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1})`

Answer (score 1):

Summing A-H horizontal and running down for 523 lines:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(iferror(mmult(A1:H523;TRANSPOSE(column(A1:H1))^0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

if I look at this formula I really think the following might be simpler. Add this to Tools > Script Editor:

```
function row_sum(range_to_sum_per_row) {
  var result_column = [];
  for (var r = 0; r < range_to_sum_per_row.length; r++) {
    var row_sum = parseFloat(0);
    for (var c = 0; c < range_to_sum_per_row[r].length; c++) {
        row_sum += range_to_sum_per_row[r][c] || 0;
    }
    result_column.push([row_sum]);
  }
  return result_column;
}
```

use this like so for performance reasons, where C:H is the range you want to sum up and A:A is a column that does not contain an empty string:

```
=row_sum(filter(C2:H, len(A2:A)>0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to add rows and sum to the last row for all values in A1:H, you can use:

```
 =ArrayFormula(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(A1:H1),ROW(A1:A)),ROW(A1:A),A1:H))
```

Alternatively, if you want be be able to add rows and columns to the spreadsheet and sum to the last of both this can also be done. Paste the following code into any cell and it will create a column of summed values for all cells in each row below and to the right of pasted cell:

```
=arrayformula(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(indirect(concatenate(REGEXREPLACE(address(row(),column()+1),"[^[:alpha:]]", ""),VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(address(row(),column()),"[^[:digit:]]", "")),":",VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(address(row(),column()),"[^[:digit:]]", ""))))),ROW(indirect(concatenate(REGEXREPLACE(address(row(),column()+1),"[^[:alpha:]]", ""),VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(address(row(),column()),"[^[:digit:]]", "")),":",REGEXREPLACE(address(row(),column()+1),"[^[:alpha:]]", ""))))),ROW(indirect(concatenate(REGEXREPLACE(address(row(),column()+1),"[^[:alpha:]]", ""),VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(address(row(),column()),"[^[:digit:]]", "")),":",REGEXREPLACE(address(row(),column()+1),"[^[:alpha:]]", "")))),indirect(concatenate(concatenate(REGEXREPLACE(address(row(),column()+1),"[^[:alpha:]]", ""),VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(address(row(),column()),"[^[:digit:]]", "")),":"),address(rows($A:$A),columns($1:$1))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `DSUM`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(DSUM(
  TRANSPOSE(FILTER({A2:A,A2:H},A2:A<>"")),
  SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)),{IFERROR(1/0);IFERROR(1/0)}))
```

notes:

- `{IFERROR(1/0);IFERROR(1/0)}` is to make zero creteria for [DSUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094281?hl=en#null).
- **{A2:A**,A2:H} -- added fake column for DSUM to mimic header column.
- may be able to cahnge the formula into `DMAX` or `DAVERAGE`

Answer (score 0):

Using Query

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(
  QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:H,A2:A<>"")),
  "select sum(Col"&JOIN("), sum(Col",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)))&")",0)
),,2)
```

notes:

- generating query string on the fly

Answer (score 0):

Answer similar to @adamL suggestion, but removing the internal `if`.

```
=ArrayFormula(
     sumif(ROW(A1:A10)*COLUMN(A1:H1)^0,ROW(A1:A10),A1:A10)
 )
```

In this case I use `ROW(A1:A10) * COLUMN(A1:H1)^0` to generate the row number matriz. To understand how it works, you can test just this part in your Google sheets:

```
= ArrayFormula(ROW(A1:A10) * COLUMN(A1:H1)^0)
```

[image: Row number matrix]

So, with your row matrix, sumif can operate for each line, is the line has the matched row number, it will be summed up.

Answer (score -3):

Let us not complicate this.
Simply put parenthesis in each of the array in the range.

```
=arrayformula( Sum( (A1:A):(H1:H) )
```

This spans not only upto 1000 rows but upto infiinity.

If you really want to limit then go

```
=arrayformula( Sum( (A1:A1000):(H1:H1000) )
```

Comment: If one of the columns have non-numeric values instead of returning an error, returns a number. Do you know why?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in google sheets. Maybe something changed over the past year but now it is perfectly valid to have `=SUM(($B1:$B10):($D1:$D10))` which is what probably broke the `ARRAYFORUMLA` wrapper.

Comment: Google Sheets evaluates `(A1:A):(H1:H)` as `(A1:H)` when in an arrayformula :(