# Google Sheet Arrayformula with multiple mathematical functions

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

How would I go about formatting an arrayformula for this?:

`=$D10*(sum($F10:$I10))`

I've tried a few different ways but none of them work. I have a bunch of rows with that formula (where of course the row number matches, so for example:

```
=$D10*(sum($F10:$I10))
=$D11*(sum($F11:$I11))
=$D12*(sum($F12:$I12)) etc...
```

I need this formula in each row but I'm trying to figure out an arrayformula so that it works when I add or subtract rows.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE************************************************************************

I've just figured out that `=arrayformula(D7:D*(F7:F+G7:G+H7:H+I7:I))` works but I might need to add and subtract columns too. Is there a way to make it work with `sum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe MMULT can be a good alternative:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(D2:D), D2:D*mmult(N(F2:I),transpose(column(F2:I2)^0)),))
```

Change ranges to suit.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve math problem is to split it.

You have two multipliers: D x sum(F:F)

The first task is to make ArrayFormula with D. It's simple:

```
=ArraFormula(D10:D1000)
```

And the hard part is to make ArrayFormula with sum. This part was already asked and [answered her](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797621/arrayformula-sum-in-google-spreadsheet)e by AdamL. In your case:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(F1:I1),ROW(A10:A1000)),ROW(A10:A1000),F10:I1000))
```

---

**And your final formula is**

```
=ArrayFormula(D10:D1000 * 
SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(F1:I1),ROW(A10:A1000)),ROW(A10:A1000),F10:I1000))
```

Comment: Thanks Max, this one seemed to work but then I noticed that it kept adding rows - managed stop it around 8,000 and delete them.

Comment: To prevent it adding new rows, use closed ranges: a1:a1000, offset(a10,,,counta(a10:a))